# What exactly is a "Special Class"?

Tags: c#, class, generics, generic-constraints

After failing to get something like the following to compile:

```
public class Gen<T> where T : System.Array
{
}
```

with the error

> A constraint cannot be special class `System.Array'

I started wondering, what exactly *is* a "special class"?

People often seem to get the same kind of error when they specify `System.Enum` in a generic constraint. I got the same results with `System.Object`, `System.Delegate`, `System.MulticastDelegate` and `System.ValueType` too.

Are there more of them? I cannot find any info on "special classes" in C#.

Also, what *is* so special about those classes that we can't use them as a generic type constraint?

Comment: I don't think this is a direct duplicate. The question isn't "why can't I use this as a constraint", it is "what are these special classes". I've had a look at those questions and they just state why it would be useless to use as a constraint, not explaining what a "special class" actually is and why it is considered special.

Comment: In my experience, classes that are used but you can't use them directly, only implicitly through other syntax, is special classes. Enum falls into the same category. What exactly makes them special, I don't know.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: that question is sort of different. I am asking for a definition of a "special class" and/or a comprehensive list of these. That question simply asks for the reason System.Array can't be a generic type constraint.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it states "[...]only the system and compilers can derive explicitly from the Array class.". It's likely this is what makes it a special class - it is treated specially by the compiler.

Comment: @RB.: wrong. This logic would mean `System.Object` is *not* a "special class", as this is valid: `public class X : System.Object { }`, but `System.Object` is still a "special class".

Comment: @Mints97 Fair point - perhaps there are multiple definitions for special :)

Comment: @Mints97, `System.Object` is a special special class, since all other types derive from it, whether they like it or not.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

From the Roslyn source code, it looks like a list of hardcoded types in `isValidConstraintType`:

```
switch (type.SpecialType)
{
    case SpecialType.System_Object:
    case SpecialType.System_ValueType:
    case SpecialType.System_Enum:
    case SpecialType.System_Delegate:
    case SpecialType.System_MulticastDelegate:
    case SpecialType.System_Array:
        // "Constraint cannot be special class '{0}'"
        Error(diagnostics, ErrorCode.ERR_SpecialTypeAsBound, syntax, type);
        return false;
}
```

- [`isValidConstraintType` in GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/1bb65b0645ede1f8cac0d3a5b7f1bdea23cba705/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Binder_Constraints.cs#L495) (updated with new types)
- [`IsValidConstraintType` is Roslyn Source Browser](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Constraints.cs,ebe65e19bb651611)
- I've found it using a [GitHub search: "A constraint cannot be special class"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22A+constraint+cannot+be+special+class%22&type=Code).

Comment: @kobi 702 becomes compiler error CS0702, as seen in the compiler output (which this question neglected to quote) and other answers.

Comment: @AakashM - Thanks! I tried to compile and didn't get the error number, for some reason. It then took me *almost* 5 minutes to find out, and didn't have enough time to edit my comment. Sad story.

Comment: @Kobi: you have to look at the _output_-window, there you find the exact compiler error code number `CS0702`.

Comment: So now the real question is _why_ are these special classes?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Maybe the reason is you cannot inherit from these types directly (except for `object`), or at least it has something to do with it. Also `where T : Array` would allow passing Assay as T, which is probably not what most people want.

Comment: The answers should focus more on the question at hand. The question is "what are special classes". Special classes cannot be used for inheritance or constratint, but remain mysterious to me, and I would like to know more. Please avoid talking about constraints only.

Answer (score 42):

I found a Jon Skeet comment from 2008 on a similar question:
Why is the `System.Enum` constraint **not** supported.

*I know this is a bit off topic*, but he asked Eric Lippert (the C# team) about it and they provided this answer:

> First off, your conjecture is correct; the restrictions on constraints
>   are by and large artefacts of the language, not so much the CLR. (Were
>   we to do these features there would be a few minor things we'd like to
>   change in the CLR regarding how enumerable types are specified, but
>   mostly this would be language work.)
>
> Second, I would personally love to have delegate constraints, enum
>   constraints, and the ability to specify constraints that are illegal
>   today because the compiler is trying to save you from yourself. (That
>   is, making sealed types legal as constraints, and so on.)
>
> However, due to scheduling restrictions, we will likely not be able to
>   get these features into the next version of the language.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Is quoting Github\MSDN better? The C# team has gave a concrete answer regarding the issue or a similar one..It can't really hurt anyone. Jon Skeet just quoted them and is pretty reliable when it gets to C#..

Comment: No need to get upset. I didn't mean this isn't a valid answer :) Was just sharing my thoughts on the foundation which is jonskeet ;p

Comment: FYI BTW I think that's me you're quoting there. :-)

Comment: @EricLippert - That makes the quote even more reliable.

Comment: Domain of link in answer is dead.

Comment: The answers should focus more on the question at hand. The question is "what are special classes". Special classes cannot be used for inheritance or constratint, but remain mysterious to me, and I would like to know more. Please avoid talking about constraints only.

Answer (score 25):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56b2hk61.aspx) it's a static list of classes:

**Compiler Error CS0702**

Constraint cannot be special class 'identifier' The following types may not be used as constraints:

- System.Object
- System.Array
- System.Delegate
- System.Enum
- System.ValueType.

Comment: Cool, seems like the right answer, good find! But where's `System.MulticastDelegate` in the list?

Comment: @Mints97: no idea, lack of documentation perhaps?

Comment: Seems as though you also can't inherit from these classes.

Comment: The answers should focus more on the question at hand. The question is "what are special classes". Special classes cannot be used for inheritance or constratint, but remain mysterious to me, and I would like to know more. Please avoid talking about constraints only.

Answer (score 14):

As per C# 4.0 Language Specification (Coded : [10.1.5] Type parameter constraints) tells two things:

> 1] The type must not be object. Because all types derive from object,
> such a constraint would have no effect if it were permitted.
>
> 2] If T has no primary constraints or type parameter constraints, its effective
> base class is object.

When you define a generic class, you can apply restrictions to the kinds of types that client code can use for type arguments when it instantiates your class. If client code tries to instantiate your class by using a type that is not allowed by a constraint, the result is a compile-time error. These restrictions are called constraints. Constraints are specified by using the where contextual keyword.
**If you want to constrain a generic type to be a reference type, use : class.**

```
public class Gen<T> where T : class
{
}
```

This will prohibit the generic type from being a value type, such as int or a struct etc.

Also, Constraint cannot be special class 'identifier' The following types may not be used as constraints:

- System.Object
- System.Array
- System.Delegate
- System.Enum
- System.ValueType.

Comment: The answers should focus more on the question at hand. The question is "what are special classes". Special classes cannot be used for inheritance or constratint, but remain mysterious to me, and I would like to know more. Please avoid talking about constraints only.

Answer (score 12):

There are certain classes in the Framework which effectively pass on special characteristics to all types derived from them *but do not possess those characteristics themselves*.  The CLR itself imposes no prohibition against using those classes as constraints, but generic types constrained to them would not acquire the non-inherited characteristics the way concrete types would.  The creators of C# decided that because such behavior might confuse some people, and they failed to see any usefulness to it, they should prohibit such constraints rather than allow them to behave as they do in the CLR.

If, for example, one were allowed to write: `void CopyArray<T>(T dest, T source, int start, int count)`; one would be able to pass `dest` and `source` to methods which expect an argument of type `System.Array`; further, one would get compile-time validation that `dest` and `source` were the compatible array types, but one would not be able to access elements of the array using the `[]` operator.

The inability to use `Array` as a constraint is mostly pretty easy to work around, since `void CopyArray<T>(T[] dest, T[] source, int start, int count)` will work in almost all situation where the former method would work.  It does, however, have a weakness: the former method would work in the scenario that one or both of the arguments was of type `System.Array` while rejecting cases where the arguments are incompatible array types; adding an overload where both arguments were of type `System.Array` would make the code accept the additional cases it should accept, but also make it erroneously accept cases it should not.

I find the decision to outlaw most of the special constraints irksome.  The only one which would have zero semantic meaning would be `System.Object` [since if that were legal as a constraint, anything would satisfy it].  `System.ValueType` probably wouldn't be very useful, since references of type `ValueType` don't really have much in common with value types, but it might plausibly have some value in cases involving Reflection.  Both `System.Enum` and `System.Delegate` would have some real uses, but since the creators of C# didn't think of them they're outlawed for no good reason.

Answer (score 10):

The following can be found in CLR via C# 4th Edition:

### Primary Constraints

A type parameter can specify zero primary constraints or one primary constraint. A primary
constraint can be a reference type that identifies a class that is not sealed. You cannot specify one
of the following special reference types: **System.Object**, **System.Array**, **System.Delegate**,
**System.MulticastDelegate**,
**System.ValueType**, **System.Enum**, or **System.Void**.
When specifying a reference type constraint, you are promising the compiler that a specified type
argument will either be of the same type or of a type derived from the constraint type.

Comment: See also: C#LS section 10.1.4.1: *The direct base class of a class type must not be any of the following types: `System.Array`,
`System.Delegate`, `System.MulticastDelegate`, `System.Enum`, or `System.ValueType`. Furthermore,
a generic class declaration cannot use `System.Attribute` as a direct or indirect base class.*

Comment: The answers should focus more on the question at hand. The question is "what are special classes". Special classes cannot be used for inheritance or constratint, but remain mysterious to me, and I would like to know more. Please avoid talking about constraints only.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think, that there exists any official definition of "special classes"/"special types".

You may think about them a a types, which can't be used with semantic of "regular" types:

- you can't instantiate them directly;
- you can't inherit custom type from them directly;
- there is some compiler magic to work with them (optionally);
- the direct usage of their instances at least useless (optionally; imagine, that you've created generic above, what generic code are you going to write?)

P.S. I'd add `System.Void` to the list.

Comment: `System.Void` gives an entirely different error when used as a generic constraint =)

Comment: @Mints97: true. But if the question is about "special", then yes, `void` is very special. :)

Comment: @Dennis: Code which has a couple parameters of a type constrained to `System.Array` could use methods like `Array.Copy` to move data from one to the other; code with parameters of a type constrained to `System.Delegate` would be able to use `Delegate.Combine` on them *and cast the result to the proper type*.  Making effective use of a generic known type to be `Enum` will using Reflection once for each such type, but a generic `HasAnyFlag` method can be 10x faster than a non-generic method.